# Change of frame transformation law for the exterior connection

Tags: differential-geometry

I’m trying to understand the transformation law for the exterior connection form given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_form#Change_of_frame). If $\omega$ is a connection form with components in frame $\mathbf e$ given by $\omega_\alpha^\beta = \omega_\alpha^\beta(\mathbf e)$ and $g$ is a matrix representing a change of basis $\mathbf e’ = \mathbf e g$, why is it that

$$\omega(\mathbf e g) = g^{-1}dg + g^{-1}\omega(\mathbf e) g?$$

Comment: What have you tried? Start with how $\omega(\mathbf e)$ is defined and differentiate $\mathbf e’$.